# How to detect and remove outliers within a dataset using boxplot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, seaborn, outliers

I want to detect and remove outliers from a stock prediction dataset.Whether I have to take one columns or whole dataset?

Comment: If you have multiple variables in your dataset with different distributions, you need to plot them separately. Not even sure what you mean by "take... whole dataset"...

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should select the particular column from which you want to remove the outlier. Not the entire dataset.

2.) If you want to remove the outliers using box plot, you can use Inter quartile range (IQR) by setting lower & upper bound values. Outliers can also be removed easily using pandas as well. Have a look at this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/how-to-remove-outliers-using-box-plot

Note: I found this article useful. https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/finding-outliers-in-dataset-using-python-efc3fce6ce32